# How to disable CKEditor context menu for certain elements?

Tags: ckeditor

I have some `<div>` elements with special classes and I want them to be disallowed for edit through the context menu.
Is there a way to do so?
I tried:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.$nonEditable = "div(myclass)";
```

and

```
allowedContent: {
                    $1: {
                        elements: CKEDITOR.dtd,
                        attributes: true,
                        styles: true,
                        classes: true
                    }
                },
                disallowedContent: "div(myclass)",
```

I also tried to exclude `<div>` from `menu_groups: '';`, but I can't exclude `<div>`'s with certain classes, only all.

[image]

PS: I need to keep the **contextmenu** plugin, just remove it for certain elements.

Comment: It seems I was incorrectly testing this with `<div class="someClass">test</div>` where no menu is shown at all. If you use `<div class="someClass"><p>test</p></div>` then menu is shown even with the code thus I have deleted my answer. Sorry for wasting your time. At the moment I don't know how to solve this problem.

Comment: @j.swiderski not completely. I've just woken up, tested again, instead of return true; I just remove the element (context menu). You can correct your answer and post again. The only thing, I don't know is it correct enough from point of view of architecture. Instead of return true I use:
if (document.getElementsByClassName("cke cke_reset_all cke_1 cke_panel cke_panel cke_menu_panel cke_ltr").length > 0)
                            document.getElementsByClassName("cke cke_reset_all cke_1 cke_panel cke_panel cke_menu_panel cke_ltr")[0].remove();

Comment: sorry for late reply, but i have a sh*t ton of things to do at work and I didn't really have time for anything else in past few days. What you have discovered is more of a hack than a real solution because you should not be removing DOM elements created by the editor but rather prevent editor from producing those elements in the first place. If it works for you it can always be used as a temporary solution. I will try to give it a second try to see if I can figure out anyway to prevent menu from being shown under certain condition.

Answer (score 1):

I have using if and Conditional (ternary) operator method to hide and disable the context menu items access

Method 1: This condition not disply the contextMenu items while right click

Method 2: This condition disable the contextMenu items functions
[TRISTATE_OFF](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#property-TRISTATE_DISABLED) ||[TRISTATE_DISABLED](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR.html#property-TRISTATE_OFF) || [Conditional_Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo('editorSpace', { toolbar: [] });
editor.on( 'instanceReady', function(e) { 
   editor.resize(200, 200); 
   editor.addCommand("myCommandEdit", {
        exec : function( editor ){          
         alert("Edit DIV"); // write your own function
      }});
   editor.addCommand("myCommandRemove", {
        exec : function( editor ){alert("Div Removed");}
    }); 
    // Listener 
  editor.contextMenu.addListener(function(element, selection ) {
  var ascendant = element.getAscendant( 'div' );
  var divCondtion = ascendant.getAttribute('class') != 'myclass';
  // Method 1
    if(divCondtion){
    return { 
        div_Edit : CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF,
        div_Remove : CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF 
     };
    }
  // Method 2

return { 
    div_Edit: divCondtion ? CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF : CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_DISABLED,
   div_Remove: divCondtion ? CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_OFF : CKEDITOR.TRISTATE_DISABLED
    };      
});

editor.addMenuItems({
 div_Edit : {
      label : 'Edit DIV',
      command : 'myCommandEdit',
      group : 'DivEditGroup',
      order : 1
   },
   div_Remove : {
      label : 'Remove DIV',
      command : 'myCommandRemove',
      group : 'DivEditGroup',
      order : 2
   }
});
```

});